# explode() not working with delimiter <br>

Tags: php, arrays, explode

At first take a look to my script:

```
<?php
$list=file_get_contents('txt.txt');
$name=explode('\r\n',$list); //file exploding by \n because list is one under one
foreach($name as $i1){
     echo ($i1);
     echo '</br>';
}
?>
```

it is showing my result (according to list) :

```
morgan daniel martin sopie tommy
```

But I have used `</br>` so that it must be showing :

```
morgan 
daniel 
martin 
sopie 
tommy
```

But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What does the HTML source code show?

Comment: Where was the HTML file created? If it's a UNIX file, `\r\n` does not exist in it, and `\n` (the UNIX line separator) will be displayed as a space.

Comment: in html and txt file : one under one

Comment: Correct use of break tag is `<br />`

Comment: ok, but i am always using this style and it's working in another script. @MuthuKumaran

Comment: @slash-bang I think `explode` didn't worked. Try using `print_r($name)` and check how many values are there.

Comment: can you upload the content of txt.txt ?

Comment: i think your code is right as your echo '<br>' is printed after each element. that means the explode() did work. if you want to look on diferent line you hv to echo '<br>'; to confirm plz do print_r($name) and display the result;

Answer (score 2):

In this situation better to use `preg_replace`... as you don't understand it well, can use below tricks... see the below code...

```
<?php
$list=file_get_contents('txt.txt');
echo implode('<br>',explode(' ',$list));
?>
```

HTML:

```
morgan<br>daniel<br>martin<br>sopie<br>tommy
```

Output Preview:

```
morgan
daniel
martin
sopie
tommy
```

if you want a break at the end too... use below one...

```
echo implode('<br>',explode(' ',$list)).'<br>';
```

Comment: this is nice solution, but still now showing a break after each elements.

Comment: don't you want a break after each element...??

Comment: no. In the list there are a break after each elements.So, i used explode to remove this break.

Comment: do you want `morgan daniel martin sopie tommy` with spaces inside or `morgan<br>daniel<br>martin<br>sopie tommy<br>`...

Comment: look at my script. It is showing with space. But i want to make it with break or new line.

Comment: it is showing with space like my script output.
look, I wanna also need each elements as string. So i used foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use php `file` instead to loop through lines of a doc:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` splits as per the given boundary string so you have to include all the whitepace charactes.

You can find the execution [see online](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/h45-svj)

So better go for regex which can be used with preg_split() with regex pattern "\s" - the whitespace character class

```
---edited---
//$list = $list = preg_replace('<br>',' ',$list);; // replace the <br> with space
$list = str_replace('<br>',' ',$list); //better than preg_replace as regex dont 
                                       //  wok better for html tags

---EOF edited---
$name = preg_split('/\s+/',$list); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($name);
echo '</pre>';
```

-----------o/p---------

```
Array
(
    [0] => morgan
    [1] => daniel
    [2] => martin
    [3] => sopie
    [4] => tommy
)
```

> note:

The **replace** since it's a hardcoded string function.

The **Regex** will take longer since it needs to parse the regex string (even if you set RegexOptions.Compiled) then execute it in the regex string then formulate the resultant string. But if you really want to be sure, perform each iteration in a million-times iterator and time the result.

Go through this:

[Shorthand Character Classes(\s)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: but now showing one under one with a lot of break under each elements.

Comment: you are echoing the break tag. remove it

Comment: do echo '<pre>';
print_r($name);
echo '</pre>'; //you can find tha actual split done

Comment: i am not understanding this (preg_split ) properly.

Comment: The `preg_split` function returns an array of values, so the `$name` variable is an array. It might be better worded as `$names`. The `print_r` function shows you the contents of the array so you can easily see how many elements it has and what the contents are. You can iterate over `$names` with your `foreach` loop and you should get the result you're expecting. Just replace your `explode` call with the `preg_split` call.

Comment: hey its edited now. Fiest we will replaceing all the <br> with space then splitting the string with space

Comment: even better would be replacing wtih str_replace as regex dont work gd with html tags

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the question but I was trying to use `explode('\<br\>',$string)` on a string that I had already run `nl2br($string)` on, so I could use the `<br>` page breaks as a delimiter and it wasn't working.

The `nl2br` actually inserts `<br />` values (which Muthu mentioned as the correct format), so if you first run `nl2br()` then want to use the inserted html page breaks as a delimiter for `explode()`, be sure to use `explode('<br />',$string)` on your results.

In Google Chrome, when I had done an inspect on the page, the results were showing with `<br>`. When I viewed the page source, I saw that they were actually `<br />`. Thought this may save someone some time if they run into similar problems.